# Get selection polygon ArcObject

Tags: c#, arcobjects

In C#/ArcObjects, is it possible to get the geometry of the polygon that is used to select features in ArcMap?
For example, when you select point features with a polygon, how do you get the geometry of that polygon?

Thank for your help!

Comment: Select by polygon? I don´t know that feature. Which version of ArcMap are you running? mAybe you ment the "select features that intersect/overlap/... the target **feature**"? Anyway you should provide what you´ve tried already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm talking about this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaTW6.png
I'm running ArcMap 10.4

Comment: Wow, didn´t know that feature.

Comment: I suppose you´d have to write your own editor-extension in order to react on ArcMap-events. However that goes far bayond a simple question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I guess you can't. The only way I see is to write your own polygon selection tool.   Making custom tool: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/ec9c3bf9-1bae-4d56-9ae6-e439dbd0f18f.htm - Making Polygon Feedback: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriDisplay/INewPolygonFeedback.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
IMxDocument doc = ArcMap.Document;
IMap map = doc.FocusMap;

selectedPolygon = map.SelectedObjects(new List<esriGeometryType> {
    esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon
});
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include an explanation of your code. This will make your answer more useful and more likely to be upvoted :)